# How to conditionally define a macro-variable inside proc iml?

Tags: sas, sas-macro, sas-iml

I have an issue with combining `proc iml`, `if/then` and `call symputx`. If I run the following code :

```
proc iml;

call symputx("noif",3);
a=1;
b=&noif;                              /* 1) : works*/
if a=1 then call symputx("withif",1);
if a=1 then print a;                  /* 2) : works */
c=&withif;                            /* 3) : doesn't work */
quit;
%put &withif;                         /* 4) : works */
```

- 1) working (and SAS/IML documentation) show I can use `call symputx`in `proc IML`
- 2) working (and SAS/IML documentation) show I can use `if/then`in `proc IML`
- 3) not working must therefore be due to some issue in combining the three statements.
- But 4) working shows the `call symputx("withif",1)` was somehow understood.

What is the proper way to conditionally define a macro-variable inside `proc iml` ?

Comment: Within data step and procedures you should get into the habit of using CALL (SYMPUT, SYMGET, etc...). The problem is that %PUT %LET %IF and the such are actually interpreted and evaluated before the procedure or data step begins. I think that if you put the first %PUT &noif before the PROC IML, you should get 3 already. Are you sure the value was initialized to something different?

Comment: That is not my real code but a -poorly chosen- reproducible example. I just wanted to show that I couldn't use `&withif` but I agree I shouldn't have used `%put`. I'll edit my question, thank you for making me realize it. However, there was a real problem beyond that bad example (that Rick Wicklin already solved).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rick Wicklin answered my question on [his blog](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/10/17/does-symput-work-in-iml/#comment-18979). Basically, I needed to add empty `else` statements after my `if/then` blocks for IML to know they were finished.